# Flex Error for alternatingItemColors property of spark datagrid component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to set alternate colors to datagrid. I wrote the following code

```
"<s:DataGrid width="777" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="center"  id="inv_dg" height="170" alternatingItemColors="#FFFFFF, #000000" fontSize="12" fontFamily="Times New Roman" dataProvider="{obj.rtlist}">"
```

But it gives me error saying "Cannot resolve alternatingItemColors for spark component datagrid". Also i want to set object value in datagrid but i am not sure if the way i did is correct. It is not working. Please help

Answer (score 1):

For DataGrid: -

Use alternatingRowColors for spark component i.e: -

```
alternatingRowColors="[#FFFFFF, #000000]"
```

and alternatingItemColors for mx component i.e:-

```
alternatingItemColors="[#0000FF, #FF0000]".
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: alternatingItemColors takes a single argument within the DataGrid tags. So, as @Mahesh has shown here, we pass the array of colors as a single quoted argument, and it later gets parsed as an array. The code in your example gets interpreted as a single string which does not resolve to a meaningful color.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the property as an array, in your case, that would be:

```
[#FFFFFF, #000000]
```